# Understanding and proving Big O notation in discrete math

Tags: calculus, discrete-mathematics, notation, computer-science

I am new to discrete math and there is something that I don't get about this big oh solution. 
The question is asking to show that $f(n)=n^2+2n+1$ is $O(n^2)$
and to prove that we set the equation $n^2+2n^2+n^2=4n^2$.

I am just confused as to why we raised the single $n$ power to $n$ squared? And the $1$ to $n$ squared?

Comment: It was a convenient choice since we know that for $n\geq 1$ we have $n^2\geq n\geq 1$ therefore $n^2+2n+1\leq n^2+2n^2+1\leq n^2+2n^2+n^2=4n^2$ so $n^2+2n+1\leq 4n^2$.  We do this to highlight the fact that $n^2+2n+1\leq kn^2$ for some $k$, which in this case is $4$ in order to invoke the very definition of being big-oh of $n^2$.

Comment: I see. That kind of makes more sense now. But is there a reason why we changed 2n+1 to 2n^2+n^2 ? @JMoravitz

Comment: Do you see why $2n\leq 2n^2$?  Do you see why $1\leq n^2$?  Do you see then why $2n+1\leq 2n^2+n^2$?

Comment: @JMoravitz yeah I think I kind of get it. but for example, if we say n>2 , why does n^2+2n+1 to n^2+n^2+n^2 ? which then k=3 ?

Comment: All that matters is that we can find a value of $N$ and a value of $k$ such that $f(n)\leq k\cdot g(n)$ for all $n\geq N$.  In reality, $n^2+2n+1$ as compared to $n^2$ we could have picked $k$ to be as close to one as we like, but the closer we get to one the larger $N$ would have to be.  We could *still* have $k=4$ even when we specify that $n>2$ since $n^2+2n+1\leq 3n^2\leq 4n^2$ for all $n\geq 2$.  We don't care about finding every pair of $N$ and $k$, just so long as we find at least one pair of $N$ and $k$.

Comment: In the case that $n\geq 2$ you have $2n \leq n\cdot n=n^2$ since $ab\leq ac$ whenever $a\geq 0$ and $b\leq c$.  For example $10=2\cdot 5 \leq 5\cdot 5=25$

Comment: @Emily: Your last comment is also a correct calculation, and also a correct proof that $f(n)$ is $O(n^2)$. Usually when we decide to use $O$-notation, we do so because we don't care so much about the value of $k$ in that context. (Obviously there are contexts in which we would care about that value, and your derivation giving $k=3$ might be more useful in that context.)